# Font weight changing while navigating website

Tags: css

I've noticed quite a few of these questions around but I also noticed that most of them don't have a clear answer.  My problem is that the font weights on my app's navbar keep changing as I navigate. Here are two pictures of before and after:

This is how it should look (kind of). It looks like this when I click on a link in the navbar.
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRab2.png)

This is when I click outside the Navbar:
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BActX.png)

You can see that the font weight drops to what is seemingly 100.
Here is what I've tried:

- Imported Lato in my html file from Google Fonts with all the weights,
  but Semantic UI CSS still cancels it out.
- I've tried adding more CSS to directly override the other css (You can see this by inspecting the
  title 'JOBTME'. It's actually better when I remove that last class I added. Other attempts at overriding keeps being overridden itself by semantic Ui.
- Tried removing blocks of my css to see if it affects the problem, but to no success.

My Index.js has styles loading after it:

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
>
> import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
> import './styles.css';
> (...)
> ```

My goal is to have a stable font-weight. Ok If anyone has any solution, I'd be grateful.

EDIT: Apparently the problem was local as I was only using one browser to view the website (Edge). Although in Chrome the problem persists, it was not evident while using Firefox. I switched to a macbook and used safari and I did not see any problem as well. To conclude, the problem seems to be on my local edge/chrome browser.

Thank you,

Robinson

Comment: I honestly can't see any difference. Logged in with Mac Firefox, and inspected the `.item` element pointing towards employees, and it never changes whatever I do to it. Lato, 14px, 500 font weight. I even tried to slow down the network, and it still looked good.

Comment: I tried in Chrome as well. No apparent change. 500 in font weight. You have a 0.9 opacity as the font-color, so it just looks like the text light up when you hover over it.

Comment: Wow really? So the problem may be local? You saw in my screenshots how I see them change. Well, if other people don't see a problem, then I suppose I'll be happy. Thank you for your time Rickard, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that often happens in menus using anchor tags is the pseudo-classes are set to a different font style. Pseudo-classes on anchors with font size inheritance get their font-size from the parent holding the anchor, not the anchor itself. Also, unlike the anchor element, pseudo-classes on anchors have the same selective weight in CSS as a normal class, so can easily cascade over your element styles, even their classes, when they are triggered. If they have different font-sizes it becomes apparent. So if you see problems, make sure you assign consistent styles on your navigation like so:

```
a.mylink,
a.mylink:link,
a.mylink:visited,
a.mylink:hover,
a.mylink:focus,
a.mylink:active
 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```